# database design - importing daily file dump

Tags: sql, database-design

I am trying to develop a database from a files that are dumped every day from a vendor. The files are decently large, and in most cases, the files have duplicate information. My question is...is it better to just upload the content from each of the files, as is, and then create a view of the most recent information, or is it better to develop a process for extracting the most recent info and replace the out dated information?

For example, if I have files like the below:

```
id      col_2   col_3   source
1       a       apple   file_1
2       b       banana  file_1
3       c       orange  file_1
1       a       apple   file_2
2       b       pear    file_2
3       c       orange  file_2
```

where the difference is col_3 for id 2.

Comment: The question is: do you ever need the historic data? If not, I would not import it into the final table. However, if you do need the historic data, then you have to store it. So, this is not really a programming question, but a business decision.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to be definitive without knowing storage vs performance considerations but I think starting position would be to just add the data each day with an identifier column (eg date added) and use views. This has the benefits of simplicity, audit trail, ability to simply rewind or view what the position was on a given earlier date and should be performant given the view will probably be a very simple sort and filter. If the data is too large you could have an archive process and clear out older data periodically to keep things in check.